# Error in procedure while changing string format

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a procedure that accepts string as input in format `dd/mm/yyyy` but I need to call this procedure from another application and I am forced to give the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

So I have extracted and changed the string to `dd/mm/yyyy` but the procedure is throwing incorrect syntax error.

Required format: `dd/mm/yyyy` e.g `'11/04/2018'`

Input format: `yyyy-mm-dd` e.g. `'2018-04-11'`

So my procedure would be

Required format is `abcdprocedure('11/04/2018')`

My formula

```
abcdprocedure(SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',9,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',6,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',1,4))
```

**Error: Incorrect syntax near ''2018-04-11''**

I am unable to understand the problem.

### Edit

Procedure is being called in below way:

```
select * from abcdprocedure('11/04/2018')
```

Comment: Is that `abcdprocedure...` line being executed in SQL? Is it appearing after an `exec` or what?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes sir it is executed in another procedure as a sql

Comment: What are you doing,calling the procedure instead of table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says -

> A table-valued function returns a single rowset (unlike stored
>   procedures, which can return multiple result shapes). Because the
>   return type of a table-valued function is Table, you can use a
>   table-valued function anywhere in SQL that you can use a table. You
>   can also treat the table-valued function just as you would a table.

First of all you should check the function 'abcdprocedure'
You can store your conversion from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy in a variable

```
 Declare @v_date date;
    @v_date=SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',9,2),'/',SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',6,2),'/',SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',1,4));
```

And then you can call your table valued funcyion

```
select * from abcdprocedure(@v_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a stored procedure within T-SQL, you may supply a *value*, a *variable* or `DEFAULT` for each parameter. You may **not** supply an arbitrary *expression*.

Move your expression out into a separate line that places the result into a variable and use *that* when calling the stored procedure.

(Also, seriously, please reconsider your use of strings here. T-SQL has perfectly good datetime related data types that are *designed* to hold `datetime`s. You only *have* formatting issues because you're working with strings)

---

EDIT

> Procdure is being called in below way:
>
> ```
> select * from abcdprocedure('11/04/2018')
> ```

Um, no. If that line of code works, then what we're talking about is *not* what T-SQL calls a stored procedure. Stored procedures are standalone blocks of code and cannot be integrated into larger queries. Again, if this works, please identify what `abcdprocedure` actually *is* (a table-valued function?) and update your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. does this mean I need to store the whole logic in another string variable and pass that variable as input

Comment: This is was developed by some other developer and I got this only a week back and I am stressed to solve this in one week.. so not trying to change the whole logic but for time being trying to makee procedure correct results

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbliever in this case how to pass the input string if it is a table valued function

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can use below query for this 

    SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',9,2),'/',SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',6,2),'/',SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',1,4));

    It will work in mysql and sql server both.

OR 

 SELECT (SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',9,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',6,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('2018-04-11',1,4))

**OUTPUT:**
11/04/2018
```